A counterexample that's not a localising ring of sets
The following is a quote from Kallenberg's Random Measures, Theory and Applications, pretty early in chapter 1.

Given a measurable space $(S,\mathcal{S})$, we say that a class $\mathcal{\hat S}\subset\mathcal{S}$ is a localizing ring in $S$ if

$\mathcal{\hat S}$ is a subring of $\mathcal{S}$,
$B\in \mathcal{\hat S}$ and $C\in \mathcal{S}$ imply $B\cap C\in \mathcal{\hat S}$,
$\mathcal{\hat S} = \bigcup_n(\mathcal{S}\cap S_n)$ for some sets $S_n\uparrow S$ in $\mathcal{\hat{S}}$.


The motivating example of a localising ring is the set of all bounded Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.
(Kallenberg has a tendency to use terms without defining them, but I'm assuming that the notation $S_n\uparrow S$ means a sequence of sets such that each is a superset of the previous one and their union is $S$, that $\mathcal{S}\cap S_n$ means $\{U\cap S_n\mid U\in\mathcal{S}\}$, and that "ring" means closed under $\cup$ and $\setminus$, rather than $\cup$ and $\cap$.)
My confusion is in seeing why the third condition is needed, given the other two. Let us define a pre-localising ring as a family of sets $\mathcal{T}$ meeting only the first two conditions,

$\mathcal{T}$ is a subring of $\mathcal{S}$,
$B\in \mathcal{T}$ and $C\in \mathcal{S}$ imply $B\cap C\in \mathcal{T}$.

Is there a nice example of a measurable space $(S,\mathcal{S})$ and a pre-localising ring $\mathcal{T}$ such that $\mathcal{T}$ is not a localising ring? That is, $\mathcal{T}$ such that the above two conditions are met but such that there does not exist a sequence $S_n\uparrow S$ with $\mathcal{T} = \bigcup_n(\mathcal{S}\cap S_n)$.
Previously, I was also looking for something weaker, namely an example of a pre-localising ring together with some specific sequence $S_n\uparrow S$ in $\mathcal{T}$ such that $\mathcal{T} \ne \bigcup_n(\mathcal{S}\cap S_n)$. However, I managed to find one for myself, which I described in a self-answer. So now I'm just looking for a pre-localising ring that's not a localising ring.

Take the trivial sigma algebra $\mathcal{T} = {\emptyset, S}$. This is closed under intersections and unions and complements, so it's a subring of $\mathcal{S}$. Now the increasing sequence must have $S$, but then $\mathcal{S} \cap S = \mathcal{S}$ contains stuff not in $\mathcal{T},$ and equality fails (as long as $\mathcal{S}$ is nontrivial).

@stochasticboy321 if $\mathcal{S}$ is nontrivial then your example violates the assumption in the second bullet point. Take any $U\in \mathcal{S}$ and $S\cup U = U$ must also be in $\mathcal{\hat S}$.

Edited the question to try and make clearer what I'm asking for - I've given the name "pre-localising ring" to a family of sets meeting the first two conditions, so I'm looking for a pre-localising ring that's not a localising ring. My point in the above comment is that $\mathcal{T}={\emptyset,S}$ is a subring but not a pre-localising ring, if $\mathcal{S}$ is non-trivial.

Ah I misread that second bullet. Whoops.


I'm assuming that the notation ... "ring" means closed under $\cup$ and $\setminus$, rather than $\cup$ and $\cap$.

I assume the first, because otherwise if $\hat{\mathcal S}$ is nonempty then we pick any $B\in \hat{\mathcal S}$; then $S\setminus B\in \hat{\mathcal S}$ and $S=B\cup (S\setminus B)\in \hat{\mathcal S}$, so the second condition implies $\hat{\mathcal S}=\mathcal S$.
Now it is easy to provide a required example. Let $S$ be any uncountable set, $\mathcal S$ be the family of all subsets of $S$ and $\mathcal T$ be the family of all finite subsets of $S$.

By closed under $\setminus$ I meant that if $A,B\in \mathcal{\hat S}$ then $A\setminus B \in\mathcal{\hat S}$. Wikipedia says this is the usual meaning of "ring" in measure theory as opposed to partial order theory, although I don't really know - I feel like it could be either and the author doesn't say.

I think I've found an answer to my second question, i.e. a pre-localising ring $\mathcal{T}$ and a specific sequence $S_n\uparrow S$ such that $\mathcal{T}\ne \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(\mathcal{S}\cap S_n)$.
Let $(S,\mathcal{S})$ be the reals with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and simply let $\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{S}$.
Then we can take $S_n$ to be the open interval $(-n,n)$, which gives us a sequence $S_n\uparrow S$. Now $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(\mathcal{S}\cap S_n)$ consists of all the bounded Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, but it's not equal to $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{S}$ because $\mathcal{S}$ contains all the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, including the unbounded ones.
However, this doesn't give an answer to my full question, because this pre-localising ring is in fact a localising ring: just take the sequence where $S_n = S$ for all $n$.
